# My program won't pass through HttpPost

Tags: java, android, httprequest

In my `CountryActivity.java` I have a HttpRequest to retrieve json information of the wikipedia.
This is the code I use `AsyncTask`:

```
   private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal");
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        try {
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            is.close();
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        showDialog(Integer.parseInt("Downloaded "));
    }
}
```

And, to call the class in my activity I use `new DownloadFilesTask();`.
The problem is, when I debug my private class, the debugger stops in the line `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal");` and it can't even retrieve the json. Do you know what may be happening? My app doesn't crash or nothing...

This is my logcat: https://pastebin.com/EgVrjfVx

Comment: why you are posting data, if you want to get json, I mean use GET method.

Comment: As @Mohit said, to fetch data from a source, you need to use `HttpGet`. `HttpPost` is for sending data.

Comment: @RoadEx Ok, I changed it to this `HttpGet httpGet= new HttpGet("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal");` but I still get the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open connection to url with `HttpURLConnection` and set `setRequestMethod()` to `GET`

```
URL obj = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();      
http.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

then gets its input stream and read via `BufferedReader` to your build.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
reader.close();
String json_string = sb.toString();           // your json data
```

Check [here full example](https://github.com/mohit008/android_repo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mohit/program/download/JsonFromUrl.java) to understand batter.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but, I put those lines of code in my onCreate or the class that I have in the question? Btw, the URL says "Malformed URL expression"

Comment: in case it didn't work..get this...[URL](https://github.com/mohit008/android_repo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mohit/program/download/JsonFromUrl.java)

Comment: Don't put it in your onCreate, your app will crash as it is networking task which is nor allowed in UI thread, put every thing in `doInBackground`

Comment: and the other things that I had, do I delete all of them and leave just the class, the doInBackground and that code?

Comment: you can pass your url to `AsyncTask` and create a method to get json as done in sample link

Comment: what I meant was, do I need to delete all of my code and create a public class with a doInBackground and paste your code?

Comment: yes, remove `DefaultHttpClient` and `HttpPost` and put every thing in `doInBackground` in `try{} catch`

Comment: so I've read the code in the `Github` that you created and I tried to copy it. Here is what I have https://pastebin.com/DKqsmu83 but, now, my app crashes with this error. Am I getting closer? https://pastebin.com/Ai8GJQ4m

Comment: can you tell me what  code is at `AsyncTask.java:325` line 325 ?

Comment: How do I find `AsyncTask.java`? I can only find `AsyncTask.class`

Comment: sorry in mean `CountryInfoActivity.java : 325`

Comment: have you tried to debug. what you getting in `json_string` ?

Comment: It gets the data it should

Comment: The problem is `ParseJson` then

Comment: so i think that answer your question

Comment: parsing json dependent on the data you get... so please ask it as another question

Comment: Yup. Thanks for your help by the way! I really appreciate it!